# Using Livepatch on Google Cloud 18.04 TLS image

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Is it possible to use the new livepatch service on Google’s GCloud image? I’m using

```
uname -r
4.15.0-1008-gcp
```

And when trying to deploy it on my 18.04TLS Server on Gcloud, I get this:

```
sudo canonical-livepatch enable [TOKEN GOES HERE]
cannot use livepatch: your kernel "4.15.0-1008-gcp" is not eligible for livepatch updates
```

Ideas?

Comment: It appears it does not suppose 17 or 18, only 14 and 16 right now.

Comment: it now supports 18, but still no gcp versions